# Facing problem install Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

When I try to install tensorflow on my pi, I get the following error:

`pip3 install tensorflow
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting tensorflow
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl (93.2MB)
    8% |██▋                             | 7.6MB 1.4MB/s eta 0:01:02
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    tensorflow from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl#sha256=25f4ff027beec1e568baf8e90a07bad59d354560533d6b37318b9efeb70beeb1:
        Expected sha256 25f4ff027beec1e568baf8e90a07bad59d354560533d6b37318b9efeb70beeb1
             Got        d168bf16455d0ac5fb8b589b267f777c98aa7191e34024c77fe90a88c5bb224b`

Comment: Are you following this? tensorflow 1.14.0 pip install tensorflow ( https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/ ) If not, can you give us the link of the package you are installing? Or try the 1.14 version if 1.13 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading the wheel file with `wget https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl` and installing it by `pip3 install tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl`.

Hopefully it works.